# Meaning of mod (-$\pi, \pi$]

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Example:

$Arg(\frac{-1-i}{i})=Arg(-1-i)-Arg(i)=-\frac{3\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{2}=-\frac{5\pi}{4}=\frac{3\pi}{4} (mod (-\pi, \pi])$

What is the meaning of $(mod (-\pi, \pi])$ and why does it make the result $\frac{3\pi}{4}$?

Comment: It should be $\pi/4$

Comment: @Henry - thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is the following: $y=x (\mod (-\pi,\pi])$ if and only if $y$ is the only number of the form $x+2k\pi$ ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$) such that $x+2k\pi\in (-\pi,\pi]$. In your case, $x=-\frac{5\pi}{4}$ does not belong to $(-\pi,\pi]$, but

$$y=x+2\pi=-\frac{5\pi}{4}+2\pi=\frac{3\pi}{4}\in (-\pi,\pi]$$

So, $-\frac{5\pi}{4} (\mod (-\pi,\pi])=\frac{3\pi}{4}.$

As another example, if $x=\frac{9\pi}{2}$, $y=\frac{9\pi}{2}+2\pi(-2)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.